# Ubuntu server 16 - keyboard and mouse not working

Tags: server

after installation Ubuntu srever 16, keyboard (usb) and mouse (usb) not working, and nothing I can do. Motherboard - new, Gigabyte GA-970A-DS3P.

**I tried:**

-Using a different usb port

-Turning the computer off and on

-Keyboard and mouse is new

**upgrade:**

PS/2 keyboard and mouse - it works, but I need usb:)

**upgrade_2:**

in BIOS usb keyboard and mouse working

**solution**

I connected to usb3 and working

thank you in advance for your help

Comment: This thread may help: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2188370 “GA-970A-DS3P revision 1 no usb 3.0” Fixed LAN and USB issues on my board. Barry

Answer (score 0):

This post isn't terribly clear about what works specifically, but the title matches my issue exactly so perhaps this will help someone.

I had `apt upgrade`d, and while the box booted to the lightdm login screen, keyboard and mouse were non-responsive (laptop internal, also I tried plugging in usb).  After a time the cursor in the password field stopped blinking as well.

It appears some X packages had been incorrectly deleted when i ran an `apt autoremove` (necessary due to a full /boot drive).

re-installing `apt install xserver-xorg-input-all` fixed the issue for me.

(to install this, boot into recovery mode, enable networking, and drop into the root shell.  When completed, reboot.)