# Is there a proper solution to "Keyboard and Mouse not working after boot" problem?

Tags: grub2, 20.04, keyboard, acpi, input-devices

I recently replaced a smashed screen on a HP Spectre x360 G2, running Ubuntu 20.04LTS. However, after booting up again I had lost the use of the laptop's touchpad and keyboard (NB. devices still functioned in the BIOS, but lost function after GRUB). There are many similar questions floated [here1](https://askubuntu.com/questions/790879/ubuntu-server-16-keyboard-and-mouse-not-working), [here2](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1273918/hp-laptop-keyboard-and-mouse-tracker-pad-not-working-after-kernel-update), [here3](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1249701/keyboard-and-mouse-stops-working), [here4](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1273923/keyboard-and-mouse-not-working-after-installing-ubuntu-20-04), [here5](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1135717/ubuntu-18-04-keyboard-and-mouse-not-working-at-login-screen), [here6](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1047588/keyboard-and-mouse-not-working-after-boot), and [here7](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1227905/keyboard-and-touch-pad-not-working-on-hp-convertible-x360-with-ubuntu-19-10). I have followed all these prompts - most suggest (re)installing `xserver-xorg-input-all` but it was all up to date, no changes.

The last link offered some help: by switching ACPI off in the GRUB settings (edit `/etc/default/grub` inserting `acpi=off` after `quiet splash`, and updating GRUB as advised). This reverted to old APM and I regained control of mouse and keyboard. However this came with other issues - namely, the kernel has no access to power status, and the keyboard was primitive (none of the special keys worked, e.g. volume/brightness).

I also tried upgrading to Ubuntu 20.10, and that brought other issues - namely it was unbearably laggy. (But I think it had full functionality).

Anyway, after a clean install of 20.04, the problem persists. Can anyone offer some advice?

Edit: Also found [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1280217/why-is-my-laptops-keyboard-screwed-up-since-kernel-5-4-0-47-till-5-8-0-20) related post, which and tried `blacklist`ing `intel-vbtn`. In the answer from @IGR94, they mention this won't work for a `/sys/class/dmi/id/chassis_type` of 31 or 32. Mine is 31, which explains why that answer does not solve.

Comment: 21.04 doesn't use Xorg at all. It uses Wayland. Have you thought about updating? You can also install Wayland manually, and switch to it via the login screen (settings option in the bottom right corner). Not sure if it will solve your issue or not.

Comment: @NateT I believe ACPI is at a lower level than Xorg, isn't it? If ACPI is not configured properly then XOrg won't run properly on top of it. Doesn't seem to be a window issue, but a hardware configuration issue.

Comment: ACPI is at a lower level than your entire OS. ACPI is an IO protocol implemented by your device manufacturer. It has a setting in the BIOS settings, so I assume it is part of the BIOS layer. In fact, if it is set, I would say that it _is_ your BIOS layer, BIOS just means "Basic IO System". In other words, ACPI is at the lowest level. The only way to change your ACPI config is to update your BIOS, which I do not recommend unless it needs to be done. If something goes wrong during the update process, your device is effectively bricked, unless you can somehow reflash it.