# Why has my bug report on Launchpad not been addressed?

Tags: bug-reporting

Several months ago I reported this bug:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-signed-hwe-5.8/+bug/1931787

(Also documented [here on Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1345402/is-there-a-proper-solution-to-keyboard-and-mouse-not-working-after-boot-proble)).

I noticed many other bug reports were of a similar nature - software configuration bugs in hardware interfaces. So I marked them as duplicates, and my post got heaps of heat! But there has been zero action for months. Can anybody explain why? Is Launchpad short of staffing/bug fixers? Is it monitored by Canonical? (I wish I had the skills to contribute, but alas I am totally amateur).

Comment: Lack of resources mostly.  Why are you asking here? This is a user support site, and all we can express here are *opinions*, but subjective answers are off-topic, as are questions asking for opinions.  Please see https://askubuntu.com/help/dont-ask  The 5.8 kernel is EOL currently anyway; to get best responses/fixes you need to detect & report the bug before it's reached *stable* or is actually released..  fixes after release (SRU) take longer.  If valid; it usually requires fix upstream too (thus needs to be re-reported upstream so they fix it into the future...)

Comment: @guiverc My question was not intended to attract *opinions*, but to gain understanding of how to progress a bug report on launchpad - or else to understand why this avenue has not born any fruit. How is this subjective and off-topic? Objective answers do not have to be narrowly-defined. On the other hand, it would simply be useful for me and others to be told why bugs filed on Launchpad fail to be acted upon. I humbly request for this topic to be re-opened.

Comment: You've already got an answer from @user535733, and I've provided my own 2c.  Where I want something worked on; I verify it's an issue with another install (clean install to ensure it's not some config I've created; a VM can be used here) then report on launchpad on whatever release I discovered it. I then test on the current *development* release (ie. has it already been fixed; currently that's *jammy*) then report that on launchpad. I then usually test in another system (eg. Debian *bookworm*, openSuSE tumbleweed etc) and if it's present there; I know it's not Ubuntu specific & go upstream

Comment: To me, your question is better suited for a forum (eg. https://ubuntuforums.org/) rather than this Q&A format; but I'm only one opinion.

Answer (score 3):

**Launchpad is not "monitored"** by Canonical in the sense you are likely thinking.

Ubuntu is a compendium of thousands of upstream projects, including the Linux kernel. Each of those upstreams has their own bug-reporting platform. Launchpad is merely a starting point. The Launchpad bug is not the end for you; it's the beginning.

**Yes, Launchpad is short of VOLUNTEERS** to *triage* bugs. New volunteers are welcome, the [Bug Squad](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/BugSquad) will train.

The specific bug you reference is for an older kernel, and it clearly has not been triaged.

**Advice: Start with the [Bug Squad](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/BugSquad) Wiki** on how to triage the bug. YOU can triage your own bug and move it forward. It does not take a degree in IT. It merely takes a bit of patience and a willingness to learn.

Generally, developers look at triaged bugs first. And, honestly, that's how they should be spending their limited time in order to help the most people.